# APIs to retrieve population, elevation and area of a place

Tags: google-places-api, wikipedia-api

I am looking for an API that can return me population, elevation above sea level and area of a city/country/state with some image URLs of it. I have looked into Wikipedia API and Google Places API but I can't find the endpoints that can return me the above-mentioned data.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO does not welcome requests for off-site resources.  It might be welcome at https://opendata.stackexchange.com, but do check their policies before re-posting.

Answer (score 0):

Wikidata can give you that, except for the elevation for country/state (not sure it is meaningful at all; you can query the highest/lowest point instead). See [API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/API) and [SPARQL](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service) docs.